# C++ Main file does not display everything

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, printing, program-entry-point

My program read a *.txt file and prints a line from the file backwards.
i wanted to get the linenumber before it does so.
after doing the loop, i got my number, but everything after my "for loop" is not printing/ working. what is wrong with my code?

```
    if (testFile.good()) {

        int countLines = 0;
        string temp;

        for (int i = 0; getline(testFile, temp); i++)
                    countLines++;

        cout << countLines;

        aline.readLine(testFile);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the stream flags so that you can "*do stuffs*" again in `aline.readLine(testFile);` after `for` loop

```
testFile.clear();
testFile.seekg(0, testFile.beg);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getline(testFile, temp)`  repeatedly until it reaches the end of the file,

then you can not read more.

you need to `rewind` it to the beginning of the file.

Comment: use `testFile.seekg(0, testFile.beg);`